# Как проверить включен ли бит в битовой маске

Tags: память, битовые-операции

Как с помощью битового сдвига проверить включен ли (к примеру) пятый бит (`0110 1100`) и почему оно так работает?

**UPD**

Как мне применить 8 битную маску `1001 1111` к верхним 8ми битам 32х битной маски? 
К примеру, `RGBA` (`0x00FFFFFF`). Как вместо нулей, вставить эти 8 бит в место `R`?

Comment: Сдвиг не нужен. Достаточно выполнить И (and, `&`) с значением где есть только 5й бит и проверить что результат не ноль

Comment: `if (v & (1 << 5)) { .... }`

Comment: @avp `(1 << 5)` создает маску `10000`?

Comment: @avp немного поправил вопрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ на первую часть вопроса дал участник @avp:

```
if (v & (1 << 5)) { ... }
```

---

На второй вопрос ответ:

```
unsigned char ch = 0xFF;
unsigned int RGBA = 0x0;
RGBA |= (ch << 24);
```

Результат:
`1111 1111 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000`.